# How to search for a whole string using IMDB api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, imdb

[IMDB API](http://imdb.wemakesites.net/) says to use the following but if i search for "The wolf of wall street" it will search by separating the words and not by the whole string.

HTML

```
<form name="search-imdb" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="hidden" value="483aa4e4-59f8-4728-804d-8f4bb4311d5a" name="api_key">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input class="form-control" required="" type="text" name="q" title="Type Name, Title, Character, etc. and hit Enter" placeholder="Type Name, Title, Character, etc. and hit Enter">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Search IMDb</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class="code"></div>
 </form>
```

JS

```
$('form[name="search-imdb"]').on("submit", function(e) {
  var form = $(this);
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
     url: "http://imdb.wemakesites.net/api/search",
     data: form.serialize(), // assuming the form has a hidden input with api_key name, containing your API key
     crossDomain: true,
     dataType: "jsonp",
     success: function(data) {
       window.console.log(data);
     }
  });
});
```

JSON

```
"data": {
        "results": {
            "titles": [
                {
                    "title": "The...",
```

Comment: well thats up to them to implement that.

Comment: @DanielA.White maybe, yet if I use this the result is correct using the whole string https://www.omdbapi.com/

Comment: why a down vote i do not know

Comment: omdb != imdb...

Comment: @DanielA.White oh ok, so basically what i should be doing is using a regex and replacing the white spaces with a+ symbol i guess. The+wolf+of+wall+street as that is providing correct results

Comment: jquery should be doing that. `+` just means space.

Comment: @DanielA.White it doesn't, try to add the + symbols on their search and it'll work http://imdb.wemakesites.net/

Comment: @DanielA.White see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demo page neglects encode the search term and instead leaves literal spaces in the url `find?q=wolf of wall street`. The API most likely interprets as `find?q=wolf` because spaces are considered invalid and the rest of the URL is ignored.

This works: http://www.imdb.com/find?q=wolf%20of%20wall%20street

To URL encode your search query [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```
var term = 'wolf of wall street';
var encodedTerm = encodeURIComponent(term);
```

URL encoding for exact search terms like this is usually preferable to using `+` for spaces because it will encode other special characters like accents and punctuation that might be in a movie title, including plus signs `+`.

Comment: it is close to what i was thinking, I was more like to add + symbols instead of the spacing. yet your seems more logic to do. Thanks, accepting in a minute

Comment: The benefit of doing proper URL encodeing is that it will encode any special characters, not just spaces. So movies with accents in the title will work.